# Very large integer inserted into a "TEXT"-type column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, text, integer

### Just experimenting

I've used this query on MySQL:

```
insert into table_name (text_col) values (1919191919191919191919191...91919191)
```

Where that integer is 174 characters long. `text_col` is of type "TEXT".
I know that integer exceeds a limit, because, instead of that number, I get a 65-long 999..9999 one, but I don't get *which limit* is exceeded. 
I've read [here](http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html) the maximum values, but I still don't get it.

What type of integer is casted if inserted into a TEXT-type column?

<kbd>Thanks, as always</kbd>

---

Edit: I know about inserting that integer as string with single quotes.

Comment: re: Edit -- Then what are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very long number (without quotes) was converted to Decimal. Since the argument exceeds the capacity for that type (namely, 65 characters), the closest value possible is substituted (all 9's).

You should probably have received a warning on your Insert. `Show warnings` should explain what happened.

Comment: Yup. The mysql GUI I use didn't showed any errors. I should've thought of that. In CLI, when using "show warnings", 1292 error appears. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question:

You're first telling the compiler to create a number of that size, which it can't really. It's a compiler limit on the size of the number

Optional workaround:

Pass it in as a string, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hehe, usually it's the other way around (people passing in numbers as strings, not strings as number). Nice to see the other error is also possible :)

Comment: yeah, I know about that, but what is the maximum size that it *can* compile? It's based on system architecture? Because I can tell you already that it can store integers larger than 18446744073709551615.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm wondering why is that 9999...999 number there and it's 65-chars long.

Comment: @nush, it's not a storage limit at all, it's a compiler limit (probably the lexer or the parser to be precise, but that depends on implementaiton). What's the compiler's limit? I'm not sure. Check the MySql compiler documentation? What is it you're trying to do? Why does passing a string not work?

Comment: Passing as strings works, of course it does. I guess if an integer has no limit imposed by MySQL (like in int- or bigint-type columns), it's limited by compiler.